# Weird IOException pre 1.6 error on 1.6 environment

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to pass `e` of type `IOException` as the cause in a new `IOException` as shown below.

```
try {
    //stuff
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IOException("Some Message", e);
}
```

This gives me the error below:

> The constructor IOException(String, IOException) is undefined

However, in 1.6, `IOException(String, Throwable)` is implemented as a constructor for this class.

It's like I'm in Java 1.5, even though everything in my project properties says 1.6!  I don't even have a 1.5 JDK installed on my hard drive!

Comment: Are you **sure** that this is a [`java.io.IOException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html) and not some other `IOException` from another package? Also note that this constructor was introduced in the Android API in **API Level 9**. If you're using anything below that, then you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Maybe try changing your build target and then change it back? Sometimes my environment acts funky and I have to do that.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Yes I am.. `import java.io.IOException;`

Comment: @Joachim Saurer however the API Level 9 was the reason so +1. Answer the question if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was referencing the incorrect android.jar in my project setup.

> Also note that this constructor was introduced in the Android API in API Level 9. If you're using anything below that, then you won't be able to use it. – Joachim Sauer Aug 4 at 14:44

Answer (score 2):

The Java version on Androind only implements 1.5 features. You should be able to use the [initCause](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29) method like this:

```
IOException e2 = new IOException("Some message");
e2.initCause(e);
throw e2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this inside your catch instead:

```
throw new IOException("Some Message", e.getCause());
```